# Strange Macro Expansion

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I recently came across this macro:

```
#define EAT(...)
#define STRIP(x) EAT x
STRIP( (1) 2 ) \\ expands to 2
```

Now can someone please explain what is going on?

How this EAT x expands?

What that parenthesis'(1)' do?

Why I can´t do the reverse like STRIP( 1 (2) ) ?

My initial intentions was spliting one argument in a macro like SPLIT(1 2) to expands to 1,2 there is a way?

Comment: Someone has played a trick: `STRIP( (1) 2 )` expands into `EAT(1) 2`. `EAT(1)` expands into nothing and only `2` remains.

Comment: Where did you find this? I cannot think of a useful reason for this.

Comment: [On this Page](http://pfultz2.com/blog/2012/07/31/reflection-in-under-100-lines/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EAT` is a function-like macro, which means it must be used like `EAT(something)`, and it expands to nothing.

So `STRIP((1) 2)` expands to `EAT (1) 2` which expands to `2`

> What that parenthesis'(1)' do?

it forms `EAT(1)` which gets expanded

> Why I can´t do the reverse like STRIP( 1 (2) ) ?

because that forms `EAT 1 (2)` and you can't use `EAT` like that.

Answer (score 3):

Lets step through the substitutions:

```
STRIP( (1) 2 )
EAT (1) 2
2
```

For the second example:

```
STRIP( 1 (2) )
EAT 1 (2)     
//error, EAT is a macro so it needs ()
```